# Python - object and variable errors

Tags: python, variables

I'm attempting to program a formula that loops until it reaches the number it is asked to loop for and give an answer to it. However, I seem to be getting variable/calling errors.

```
def infinitesequence(n):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for values in range(0,n+1):
        b = b + 2((-2**a)/(2**a)+2)
        a += 1
    return b
```

returns

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

while

```
def infinitesequence(n):
    a = 0
    for values in range(0,n+1):
        b = b + 2((-2**a)/(2**a)+2)
        a += 1
    return b
```

returns

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: What is `2((-2**a)/(2**a)+2)` supposed to do then? Are you forgetting a `*` multiplication there?

Comment: In your second example you simply removed the `b = 0` line; that's indeed going to lead to a new error.

Comment: The ** is for a formula.

Comment: `**` is the exponentiation operator and not what I am talking about. I am talking about the `2` at the start. I think you meant to *multiply by 2* here.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is correct. I'll mark it when I can. Proves how much of a rookie I am >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2((-2**a)/(2**a)+2)` is trying to use that first `2` as a function. You are asking Python to *call* `2()` by passing in the result of the `(-2**a)/(2**a)+2` expression, and that doesn't work:

```
>>> 2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Perhaps you were forgetting to use a [`*` multiplication operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) there:

```
2 * ((-2 ** a) / (2 ** a) + 2)
```

Your `UnboundLocal` error stems from you removing the `b = 0` line, which was not the cause of your original error.